# How exactly does the Laplace transform map something to the frequency domain?

Tags: intuition, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

I've often heard the claim that the Laplace transform reduces functions to sums (or rather integrals) of a bunch of exponential functions, like a Fourier series reduces things to sums of sinusoids and a Fourier transform reduces things to integrals of sinusoids.

While this is clear for the Fourier transform, which is its own inverse, I'm having trouble understanding how this is so for the Laplace transform.

The Laplace transform of $e^{at}$, for example, is $1/(s-a)$. If the "integral of exponentials" thing was correct, it would've been $\delta(s-a)$. The integral $\int_0^\infty e^{st}/(s-a) ds$ actually diverges.

It seems to me that it is not $f(t)$, but rather $F(s)$, which is written as an integral of exponentials of the form $e^{-st}$, and the weight on each $t$ is given by $f(t)$. Am I right?

Comment: Let $F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-st}dt$ the (bilateral) Laplace transform of $f(t)$. Then $\widehat{f}_\sigma(\xi) = F(\sigma+2i\pi \xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-\sigma t}e^{-2i \pi \xi t}dt$ is the Fourier transform of $f(t) e^{-\sigma t}$. And hence if everything converges $f(t) =  e^{\sigma t}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{f}_\sigma(\xi)e^{2i \pi \xi t}d\xi = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\sigma+2i\pi \xi)e^{(\sigma+2i \pi \xi) t}d\xi$

Comment: I don't see what you mean with $\delta(s-a)$ (which doesn't make sense for $s \in \mathbb{C}$). For now you should avoid looking at distributions.

Comment: @reuns So the integration should be done on the complex plane? And how does $f(t)$ still show dependence on $\sigma$?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if $\delta(s-a)$ doesn't make sense for $s-a\in\mathbb{C}$ -- you can just define some function over the complex plane that goes to infinity like the delta function near 0. The point is that $e^{at}$ is a single exponential of frequency $a$, so you shouldn't need to do an integral. With the Fourier transform, for example, this is exactly what happens to $e^{i\omega_0t}$.

Comment: The Dirac delta $\delta(x)$ isn't a function, and it isn't defined for $x \in \mathbb{C}$ (it is defined by $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) \phi(x)dx = \phi(0)$ whenever $\phi$ is continuous). Did you work on my comment ? $f(t) e^{-\sigma t}$ as well as its Fourier transform $\widehat{f}_\sigma(\xi)$ depend on $\sigma$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform#Mellin.27s_inverse_formula) which is exactly what I wrote with the notations of complex analysis.

Comment: And be careful : $e^{at}1_{t > 0}$ is not the same as $e^{at}$.

Comment: @reuns Yeah, I did work through your comment, which is why i'm confused about your final result, which says that $f(t)$ (not its fourier transform or $f(t)e^{-\sigma*t}$) is dependent on $\sigma$.

Comment: Yes. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\sigma+2i\pi \xi)e^{(\sigma+2i \pi \xi) t}d\xi$ doesn't depend on $\sigma$ because (assuming everything converges) then $F(s)$ and $F(s) e^{st}$ are complex analytic (see [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula))